# OpenCL Child Kernel Error

Tags: c++, opencl

Aloha,
I'm struggling with OpenCL child kernel feature.
Kernel SRC (Minimal example):

```
kernel void launcher()
{
    ndrange_t ndrange = ndrange_1D(1);
    enqueue_kernel(get_default_queue(), CLK_ENQUEUE_FLAGS_WAIT_KERNEL, ndrange,
    ^{
    size_t id = get_global_id(0);
    }
    );
}
```

stdafx.h:

```
#pragma once
#define __CL_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS
#define CL_HPP_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS
#define CL_HPP_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 200

#include "targetver.h"



#include <CL/cl2.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
```

Full SRC (Minimal):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
std::string kernel2_source(
    "kernel void launcher() ""\n"
    "{ ""\n"
    "    ndrange_t ndrange = ndrange_1D(1);""\n"
    "    enqueue_kernel(get_default_queue(), CLK_ENQUEUE_FLAGS_WAIT_KERNEL, ndrange,""\n"
    "    ^{""\n"
    "    size_t id = get_global_id(0);""\n"
    "    }""\n"
    "    );""\n"
    "}""\n");

//Number of Input Elements
constexpr int numTriangles = 10;

cl_int errorcode = CL_BUILD_ERROR; //Has to be set to build error, because errorcode isn't set when exception occurs
                                   //Move variable definitions out of main for test purposes;
//Numerous definitions
cl::Program program;
std::vector<cl::Device> devices;
std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
cl::CommandQueue queue;
cl::Program::Sources source{ kernel2_source };

int main() {
    try {
        // Query for platforms
        cl::Platform::get(&platforms);
        std::cout << "Num Platforms: " << platforms.size() << std::endl;

        // Get a list of devices on this platform
        platforms[0].getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &devices);
        std::cout << "Using platform: " << platforms[0].getInfo<CL_PLATFORM_NAME>() << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Num Devices: " << devices.size() << std::endl;

        // Create a context for the devices
        std::cout << "Using device: " << devices[0].getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>() << std::endl;

        //Create a context for the first device
        //cl::Context context({ devices[0]});

        cl::Context context({ devices[0] });
        // Create a command−queue for the first device
        queue = cl::CommandQueue(context, devices[0]);

        cl::DeviceCommandQueue deviceQueue;
        deviceQueue = cl::DeviceCommandQueue(context, devices[0]);
        // Create the program from the source code
        program = cl::Program(context, source);
        std::cout << "Building Program" << std::endl;

        // Build the program for the devices
        errorcode = program.build("-cl-std=CL2.0 -g");

        std::cout << "Success!" << std::endl;

        cl::Kernel kernel = cl::Kernel(program, "launcher");
        cl::NDRange global = numTriangles;
        cl::NDRange local = 1;
        queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NullRange, global, local);
        std::cout << "finished" << std::endl;
        std::cin.get();

    }
    catch (cl::Error error)
    {
        std::cout << "Error!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << error.what() << "(" << error.err() << ")" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Errorcode: " << errorcode << std::endl;
        if (errorcode != CL_SUCCESS) { //...
            std::cout << "Build Status: " << program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_STATUS>(devices[0]) << std::endl;
            //std::cout << "Build Status: " << program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_STATUS>(devices[1]) << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Build Options:" << program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_OPTIONS>(devices[0]) << std::endl;
            //std::cout << "Build Options:" << program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_OPTIONS>(devices[1]) << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Build Log:" << program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(devices[0]) << std::endl;
            //std::cout << "Build Log:" << program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(devices[1]) << std::endl;
        }
    }
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Num Platforms: 1
Using platform: AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Num Devices: 2
Using device: Hawaii
Building Program
```

=> Exception.

There appears an uncaught exception which is strange, because all build error should be caught.
The `ndrange_1D(1)` is just for testing purposes (and to produce an acceptable amount of dummy output).
The device (AMD R9 390X) is OpenCL 2.0 capable.

Any ideas how to fix this?

EDIT:
Even **not** using exceptions and using errorcodes throws this an exception!

Comment: is try/catch special for opencl-2.0? Everyone was using return value of CL_SUCCESS or error codes from each api command for version 1.2.

Comment: It's not a OpenCL2.0 thing but rather a C++ Bindings thing. Using `#define CL_HPP_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS` allows you to use exceptions.

Comment: any solution on this? I am having the same issue.